# Getting the average number of orders per day using mysql

Tags: mysql, average

I have the following table structure:

```
ID, User_ID, DateTime
```

Which stores a user id and datetime of an order purchased. How would I get the average number of orders a day, across every row?

In pseudo code I'm thinking:

1. Get total number of orders
2. Get number of days in range (from first row to last row).
3. Divide 1. by 2. to get average?

So it would return me a value of 50, or 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the date range, and you are not guaranteed to *have* and order on these dates, you can't just subtract the max(date) from min(date), but you *know* the number of days before you run the query, therefore simply:

```
select count(*) / <days>
from mytable
where DateTime between <start> and <end>
```

Where you supply the indicated values because you know them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_time) as days, AVG(count(*))
from table 
group by days
```

I have not tested the query, its just the idea, I guess it should work.